# Azure Functions and local TCP server

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have one HTTP triggered Azure functions that gets data from DataBase and sends it via TCP/IP to a local server written in Python. Localy everything works. But after I deploy the function to the Azure portal, I cannot connect to local server to send data there. How I can fix this?

Below is my code:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
const net = require('net');

var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;  


// connect to DB
var config = {
    authentication: {
        options: {
            userName: '',
            password: '' 
        },
        type: 'default'
    },
    server: '', 
    options:
    {
        database: '', 
        encrypt: true,
    }
};  

if (req.body) {

    var connection1 = new Connection(config);
        connection1.on('connect', function(err){ 
        console.log("Connected to DataBase");

        var request1 = new Request("SELECT 
KeyFigure.id,KeyFigure.unit_id,KeyFigure.week,KeyFigure.daily_gain,
FROM KeyFigure INNER JOIN KeyFigureDelivery ON 
KeyFigure.id=KeyFigureDelivery.key_figure_id WHERE 
KeyFigureDelivery.delivered=0", function(err, rowCount, rows){  
            console.log(rowCount + ' row(s) returned');
            if (err) {
                var client_1 = new net.Socket();
                client_1.connect(9000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
                    console.log('Connected to Server');
                    client_1.write(JSON.stringify("No data to send...from 
KeyFigure"));//'Data was written to a Data Base.');
                    client_1.destroy(); //close()
                });
                console.log("Error in Database KeyFigure");
                connection1.close();
                console.log("Disconnected_1 because of Error");
            }
            if (rowCount == 0) {
                var client_2 = new net.Socket();
                client_2.connect(9000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
                    console.log('Connected to Server');
                    client_2.write(JSON.stringify("No data to send...from 
KeyFigure"));//'Data was written to a Data Base.');
                    client_2.destroy(); //close()
                });
                connection1.close();
                console.log("Disconnected_1 because of 0 Rows")
            }
        });  

        request1.on('row', function(columns) {
            var DataToSend = [];
            var rowdata = new Object()
            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                //console.log("%s\t%s", column.metadata.colName, 
column.value);
                //DataToSend.push([String(column.metadata.colName) + ":" 
+ String(column.value)])
                    rowdata[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
                });
            DataToSend = rowdata
            var client1 = new net.Socket();
            client1.connect(9000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
                console.log('Connected to Server');
                client1.write(JSON.stringify(DataToSend));//'Data was 
written to a Data Base.');
                //client.destroy(); //close()
                client1.on('data', function(data) {
                    console.log('Received: ' + JSON.parse(data).id);
                    //client.destroy();
                    var dataIn1 = JSON.parse(data)

                    if (dataIn1.status == 200){
                        var connection_in1 = new Connection(config);
                        connection_in1.on('connect', function(err){ 
                            console.log("Connected");
                            var request_in1 = new Request("UPDATE 
KeyFigureDelivery SET delivered = 1 WHERE key_figure_id= 
"+dataIn1.id+";", function(err, rowCount, rows){  
                            //console.log(rowCount + ' row(s) returned'); 
UPDATE KeyFigureDelivery SET delivered = 1 WHERE key_figure_id= 
"+data+";"
                            if (err) {
                                console.log("Error in Database 
KeyFigure");
                            }
                            });  
                                request_in1.on('row', function(columns) {
                                    columns.forEach(function(column) {                    
                                    });
                                    context.res = {
                                        status: 201, 
                                        body: "Input Data is Valid and 
Accepted.\n"
                                    };
                                    connection_in1.close();      
                                });
                                connection_in1.execSql(request_in1);  
                        }); 
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Data was not delivered!!..from 
Server...KeyFigure")
                    } 
                });
                client1.on('error', function(err){
                    console.log("Error: "+err.message);
                });
                //client1.destroy();
                connection1.close();
            });
        });
        request1.on('doneInProc', function (rowCount, more, rows) { 
            connection1.close();
            console.log("Connection 1 closed...")
        });
        connection1.execSql(request1); 
    });
}
else{
context.res = {
        status: 400,
        body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request 
body."
    };

};
```

What I need is: (azure function) get data from Data Base, send it to a server, if data is valid - server sends a message to client (azure function), update table in data base. all this in one HTTP triggered Azure Function. How it is possible to do?

Thank you for your help

Comment: where do you expect should "local server" be? It obviously won't be 127.0.0.1 when deployed to an Azure Function.

Comment: i made a local server on my computer. and 127.0.0.1 is not the IP adress I have (just for safety wrote it here)

Comment: See my answer below. Web sockets are currently not supported

Comment: forgot about error message I get...Error: connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:9000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web sockets are not (currently) supported in Azure Functions. See this Github thread for details: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/738

> In summary, there are open issues around design, billing, and
>   technical implementation. I think there are reasonable solutions to
>   these issues and we just need to start working on them once this
>   feature is high enough on our list of priorities.

If you have a real case, you should comment on that Github thread.

Comment: so nothing can be done to connect to local server from azure functions?

Comment: sure you can. Using most protocols will work fine, e.g. HTTP or JDBC, or ... Just not over sockets.